# OpenVPN Confusion - Server and client on one machine?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, openvpn, raspbian

I have searched all over the internet and tried so many things.. but I cannot seem to figure this out.

I have a Raspberry Pi.
I have an ethernet, but I have access to a wireless if I needed it.

1). I would like that my Rpi boots, immediately connects to the remote OpenVPN server I pay to have.

2). With this connection established, I would also like to push all DNS the pi itself uses, through the tunnel, using DNSCrypt. (Is this possible?) when I use x11 with midori, apparently my DNS leaks. I don't know why. It's not the browser.

3a). I would like that I could connect to an Openvpn-server running on my pi. Once connected from remote location, all my data would run through my pi vpn at home, and out through the first, paid, connected tunnel.

3b). I would settle for just being able to OpenVPN connect to the server on the pi, while the Openvpn client was active. Then I could at least admin my pi and access my network from wherever.

I made a diagram.

[This shows what I want to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xQgz.png)

Comment: This seems possible, you just need to run two OpenVPN instances, one for each connection. Don't mix up everything into one pile – set up VPN first, worry about DNS later.

Comment: So, if I have openvpn client up and working/connected... 
Then I make an openvpn server. How can I connect to my pi via openvpn, upstream through the outgoing openvpn client already running?

Comment: @Zapp You need to give your remote clients a default route pointed to the PI on VPN1(yours) and then give the pi a default route pointed to your providers VPN server on VPN2(paid), then traffic should flow as desired.

Comment: Unfortunately, once you connect your Pi to the paid VPN service, it will probably redirect your Pi default gateway which will break incoming connection from your remote PC.  What you want can be done but it will require some detailed bash script to manage your routing.

Comment: @dotvotdot I don't suppose you would assist? My network is pretty straightforward